# 'Quantized' increase in velocity? Or 'quantized' acceleration perhaps?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, electrostatics, quantum-electrodynamics

If you accelerate any charged elementary particle in an electric field, is the acceleration "quantized"? And can it be observed in a setup like in the schematic drawing below?

In the hypothetical experiment, positive elementary particles are accelerated by an electric field. You either move one plate electrode or vary the voltage, to make the particles 'feel' the field for different periods of time.

How do you solve such problems? Has an experiment like this ever been done? And what was the result?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean exactly by “quantized” in this context? Not all quantum observables have discrete spectrum of eigenvalues.

Comment: Will the detector show discrete spots, such as in the picture.

Comment: My view of acceleration of a charged elementary particle in an electric field is that it has a certain velocity during a certain time span (and travels a certain distance) and then, as if touched by a magic wand, it has a higher velocity, for the same time span, and so on. If the field is homogeneous and if we can ignore relativistic effects, the same 'amount' of velocity is added every time it increases its velocity. Am I correct?

Comment: I wrote in the original posting that "You either move one plate electrode or vary the voltage". That should really be " You either move one plate electrode or vary the time that the voltage is on".